# despues de conectar a una BD Mongo, como transformo un BSON en JSON utilizando Python o lenguaje R sin utilizar drivers para un ODBC?

Tags: python, r, mongodb, powerbi

Necesito realizar un reporte de **Power BI** de Microsoft el cual no acepta conexiones a bases de datos no relacionales, pero permite introducir scripts en Python o en lenguaje R que es lo que estoy intentando.

Hasta el momento solo he logrado realizar la conexión a la BD de **Mongo** en los 2 lenguajes, pero no se como transformar la información en un **JSON** para que lo pueda leer Power BI ya que los datos salen en formato **BSON** que es una especie de JSON anidado o con tipos de datos no reconocidos por JSON.

Este es un ejemplo de documento que devuelve la BD mongo, cuando hago la conexión con Power BI, todo lo que esta dentro de Driver me lo marca como error y solo muestra correctamente la parte final que es `createdAt` y `_v` :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e29ba81e039766c3ca5e095"),
    "driver" : {
        "speed" : "2",
        "typeOfActivity" : "Sin actividad",
        "firebaseToken" : "",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dfac0cdea8fa00007a55ea7"),
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [ 
                -89.5719092, 
                20.9951776
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e29ba81e03976d50fa5e097"),
            "type" : "Point"
        },
        "email" : "usuario@gmail.com",
        "firstName" : "Ismael",
        "lastName" : "Apellido",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-23T15:23:45.441Z")
    },
    "geoFences" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-23T15:23:45.442Z"),
    "__v" : 0 }
```

gracias de antemano por el apoyo.

Saludos.

Comment: Un título contiene la idea general, la descripción del mismo va en el cuerpo del mensaje. Saludos :D

Comment: te refieres a [esto](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/connect/powerbi/)

Comment: @JackNavaRow eso es precisamente lo que el OP no puede usar (por algún motivo). En el título de la pregunta dice: *sin utilizar drivers para ODBC*. Lo que debe hacer en todo caso es la conversión del resultado en el lenguaje de script que use para devolverlo a PowerBI como un JSON válido.